# Using Stored Procedures the right way

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have written a web application using Entity Framework to perform CRUD operations on the database.

I want to change this so that Stored Procedures will be used for the CUD operations. Although I've used Stored Procedures extensively in other projects; after reading around, I can see that there is a school of thought where Stored Procedures should not contain any business logic (which I had been doing previously).

Has anyone taken this approach when building applications with Stored Procs? and does this approach work? Assuming this approach is the correct, then I'm assuming that Stored Procs should only do basic CRUD operations?

Also - My web application is a password sharing system, that allows admins to give individual users access to individual passwords. So when a password is created, the Stored Proc would write the password to the database, Administrators need to automatically be given access to the password... so taking the "leave business logic out of SPs" approach, should the Add_Password SP contain some logic to create the relevant records for the admins to have access, or should this be done through a loop calling an Add_Access SP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with many technical topics, there is a wide range of opinions based on either Idealism, Pragmatism, or Ignorance. Just ask if it is ok to use a CURSOR and you will see rather quickly :).

I feel that the "No Business Logic" mantra is mostly idealism since it seems that relatively few people take the time to discern what exactly constitutes actual "Business Logic" as separate from what I call "Data Logic". Data Logic is using the RDMBS to the best of its abilities to efficiently manipulate data.

I take a more pragmatic approach and look at what is actually being done and where is it most efficient to do that operation. In your specific case of assigning the related records either in the proc or in the app layer via a loop, I think it is foolish to do such a thing in the app layer as you gain nothing that a 1 line comment couldn't have done *but* you do incur a huge cost for making repeated database calls. Sure, those costs could be reduced by wrapping the looped calls into a transaction and using the same open connection, but that will never be as efficient (i.e. scale as well) as a simple set-based statement in a stored procedure.

Don't get me wrong, I definitely agree that algorithms should be in the app layer, but once you know what data should be persisted, it should be handed off to the DB to do the work.

For example, your `Add_Password` proc could be something like:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Add_Password
(
  @UserID       INT,
  @Password     NVARCHAR(50),
  @PasswordID   INT OUTPUT = -1
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRY

   BEGIN TRAN;

   INSERT INTO dbo.Passwords (UserID, [Password])
   VALUES (@UserID, @Password);

   SET @PasswordID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

   INSERT INTO dbo.PasswordAccess (UserID, PasswordID)
      SELECT  usr.UserID, @PasswordID
      FROM    dbo.Users usr
      WHERE   usr.UserType = 1; -- Assuming 1 = Admin

   COMMIT TRAN;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   ROLLBACK TRAN;

   THROW;
END CATCH;
```

In the app code, just do:

```cs
// Insert new password and assign access to all Admin-level Users (i.e. UserType = 1)
SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Doing this all in the app layer means getting all of the "Admin" UserIDs and calling `AddAccess` for each one? That seems convoluted as well as inefficient.

In general, try to stick to just doing "Data Logic" (such as the example above) in the DB, *but* do not get so caught up in the ideal of "no business logic in the DB" that you let your project suffer if there is a situation that truly benefits from putting some of it in the DB. Just be sure to put comments (useful comments with enough info / detail to communicate an actual idea instead of a mystery) in the app code as to what is happening in the DB call being made.

**EDIT:**
For the sake of completeness regarding this type of operation, there are times when you are adding something new, but the list of associations is stored in a collection in the app layer and not in the database. Would it then be ok to call an `AddPassword` stored procedure that returns the new `PasswordID` and then use that in a loop over an `Admins` collection that calls `AddAccess` passing in the new `PasswordID` and one `UserID` at a time? The answer is still "no". In this case you would loop through the `Admins` collection only to format either a CSV string or attribute-based XML document to be passed into a stored procedure. If the list of IDs extracted from the collection is going to be large (i.e. over 100k items, maybe) then a TVP (Table-Valued Parameter) might be more efficient, but for small lists a TVP *can be* over-engineering (obviously do what is best for each situation).  Hence, the example proc above would change slightly to be something like:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Add_Password
(
  @UserID       INT,
  @Password     NVARCHAR(50),
  @AdminIDs     VARCHAR(MAX), -- CSV list of UserIDs that are Admin / UserType = 1
  @PasswordID   INT OUTPUT = -1
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRY

   BEGIN TRAN;

   INSERT INTO dbo.Passwords (UserID, [Password])
   VALUES (@UserID, @Password);

   SET @PasswordID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

   INSERT INTO dbo.PasswordAccess (UserID, PasswordID)
      SELECT  split.[Value], @PasswordID
      FROM    dbo.SqlClrOrXmlStringSplitter(@AdminIDs, ',') split;

   COMMIT TRAN;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   ROLLBACK TRAN;

   THROW;
END CATCH;
```

Comment: @binks : any time :). I just updated the SQL a little as it really should have TRY / CATCH and transaction handling. Also, added an EDIT section that hopefully paints a clearer picture. Upvote? :D

Comment: +1 for such a detailed answer , @binks when someone spends this much time to solve your problems for you, the person deserves an upvote, it encourages people to provide quality answers.

Comment: @M.Ali Sorry, I just assumed I needed to click the "answered" tick.  Duly noted.

Comment: @srutzky thanks, that helps with the "edit permissions" bit :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe in an ideal world you would want most of your business logic to be in some sort of configurable form.  SP's by themselves are not configurable to end user, but can call objects that contain configuration information.  Sometimes based on requirements it just makes sense to have the business logic in an SP, and there isn't any law you're breaking by doing that.

If the hard and fast rule is an administrator always needs to see a password, there might be other ways around it rather than granting access to the password.  The access could be implicit to a user type always, thus eliminating the need for the call to add access.  If the access to administrators is selective, well you can build configuration information around that in tables as well.

If this is a retrofit of an existing system, then sure your approach to add access in the Stored procedure will do just fine, but I do like the idea of breaking that functionality off as to make it more modular.  A call to another SP works just fine, or that could likely be updated from a trigger depending on the specifics of the system.